# Universal Image Loader ViewPager how to implement

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

It's almost 2 months now for me, coding in java, android especially.
I came into a problem and I've been struggling for over two days now.

Basically, I have a database full of strings(url).
I am trying to build an application where I pass the selected (by my query) Urls into the Universal Image Loader and eventually get a Viewpager with all those images that have been downloaded from the UIL.

I have build my own adapter (in order to use it for the ViewPager) but I don't know how to use the Universal Image Loader and create that ViewPager.

Here is my code:
**MenuImages.java**

```
public class Menu_images extends Activity {


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.menu_gallery);

 Bundle map = getIntent().getExtras();
 String rest_name=map.getString("key");
 String area=map.getString("key2");

 loadGalleryImages(rest_name, area);


 }

private void loadGalleryImages(String rest_name, String area) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> images_url = db.getImagesUrl(rest_name, area);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);

    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

}
```

**MyPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;


private Integer[] Imgid = {
         R.drawable.gallery_photo_1, R.drawable.gallery_photo_3, R.drawable.gallery_photo_1
};

public MyPagerAdapter(List<String> images_url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public int getCount() {
    return Imgid.length;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {      


    ImageView img = new ImageView(collection.getContext());


    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = Imgid[0];
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = Imgid[1];
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = Imgid[2];
        break;
    }

    img.setImageResource(resId);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(img, 0);
    return img;
}
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
```

}

**DataBaseHandler.java**

```
public List<String> getImagesUrl(String rest_name, String area) {
    List<String> images_url = new ArrayList<String>();

     // Select All Query
       String selectQuery = "a query goes here";


       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);





    // looping through all rows and adding to list
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               images_url.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_images")));
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }

       // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

       return images_url;
}
```

As you can see, I am getting a List with all the String(urls) from the DataBaseHandler.
I actually need to remove the array Interger[] from my MyPagerAdapter and replace it dynamically with the List that I retrieve from my DataBaseHandler (the one with the URLs).

To sum up with, I am trying to make Universal Image Loader use all the URL I pass to it and create a viewpager with those.

I would be eternally grateful, if you could give me a hand with that, cause I am starting to freak out. I have spend many days on this part, searching for hours and haven't found something that suits me.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long talk,
Harris.

Comment: Here is a perfect [example](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) for you. Download the source code on the upper right corner, and run the application. You can study the source code, it has all you need. It is a bit advance, don't freak out. Post questions if you have any.

Comment: Let me test this in a bit and report back here.

Comment: From testing the source code in your link, this must be exactly what I am looking for. How will I be able to implement it in my current project though?

Comment: The demo code is under apache license, you can just copy part of the source code you need, e.g. the part that handle loading and display image.

Comment: I think I found how to implement it, at last. Please write your first comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am glad that it helps you. I copy my first comment as answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a perfect [example](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) for you. Download the source code on the upper right corner, and run the application. You can study the source code, it has all you need. It is a bit advance, don't freak out. Post questions if you have any.

Comment: This example works for 4.1 android. Can you please tell me how can I implement it for lower api levels? Thanks.

Comment: What API level you are talking about? It should work all the way back to 2.2.

Comment: Well, apparently it's not. When I change the API level from 4.1 to 2.3.3, some of the methods are not working. It doesn't even reach some ids (eg. R.id.something) or some constants. SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE as an example. It cannot import import android.app.ActivityOptions; which is one of the needed imports :S etc...any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post which classes you are using from the demo code? `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` is used to hide the status bar, which you don't need it before HCM, so please post the code that cause problem, so I can take a look at it.

Comment: I have loaded the Bitmapfun apk into my android phone and it's working fine. This means that the error is somewhere between the implementation of my code and the bitmapfun code. Is it possible to write a button listener and when that button is clicked, the bitmapfun project gets loaded? Thanks for all the time you take to help me mate.

Comment: The minimal target sdk of demo code is 7, so it should work fine on 2.3. If you check carefully, you should see something like `Utils.hasHoneycomb()`, look at the `Utils` class, it has all those checking for the sdk level, you can use that class to check the sdk level. That is all I can help, otherwise you have to post you source code, then I can see what goes wrong.

Comment: Lets just say I have a button named button_test. I first use the findViewById(R.id.button_test). Then I create a button click listener (src.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second_Activity.class));
    
   }
  });) What's the name of the second activity, the one in the bitmapfun I should use in order to connect the rest of my code with the bitmapfun activities?

Comment: If you go to `AndroidManifest.xml`, you should see only all the activities right there. Whichever declares `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>` is the first going to be called when launching from home launcher.

Comment: In that case, I already got my main activity declared. Which activity do I have to start (startActivity) when I click a button in order the viewpager to be used? Cause when I export the apk and upload it in my 4.0.3 android phone, and use the test_button to start the bitmapfun activity, it crushes. But when I load the bitmapfun project alone, it loads just fine.

Comment: I will suggest you start from basic Android development tutorial. This is a basic question. Watch some tutorials, and get the idea how android works.

Comment: ImageGridFragment.java this is where I have the problem. In the onItemClick method, it says above @TargetApi(16) and If I remove this I get an error. When I load the apk in my android phone, this is the part(the clicking the image) where I get the crash. It doesn't load the viewpager with the image when you click the image from the gridview. :S Any thoughts?

Comment: ps. It's working fine in the emulator (2.3.3) but not in my android phone (4.0.3)

Comment: Any idea on how you can populate the bitmapfun sample using url strings retrieved from my database?